# Using amazon S3 to host remote Hg Repositories

Tags: mercurial, amazon-s3

Is it feasible (financially) to host centralised mercurial repositories on Amazon S3. As far as i can see, just by buying an S3 account, and a domain name, i could essentialy use it as a remote server. On the basis that its 0.15 dollars per month per gb and and all of my repos together probably come to less than 300mb that would make it ridiculously cheap... or am i missing something?

Comment: FYI, Bitbucket.org is running on Amazon S3, so you wouldn't be the first to host Mercurial repositories there :-)

Comment: If it's only for your use, check out Kiln - prices start at free, and it has build in Code Review and an awesome web app http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/StudentAndStartup.html (Despite the name, it is not only for Students/Startups)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible **but** you'll lose some speed/efficiency versus hosting it somewhere you can run executables.  Mercurial has server side code that gets executed during clone, push, and pull.  In a normal setup you trigger that remote execution by running a cgi or wsgi over http or by running the hg executable over ssh.  Neither of those are available over S3.

There are, however, a few ways you could get around that limitation.  One has more restrictions and one requires more setup:

Option one is to s3put the repo up there and access it via `http-static://` URLs, which is a read-only fallback mode that [mercurial offers](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StaticHTTP).  It's not very efficient, and as mentioned, it's read-only.

Option two is to mount s3 on your local filesystem using something like [s3fs or fuse](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/).

In neither case would Mercurial's nifty web interface be available from s3.

Comment: I setup things as you describe using s3fs to host the repository. However, I'm getting corrupted repositories every now and then when I abort a push. I can't say for sure, but my best guess is that mercurial doesn't play nice with the "eventual consistency" provided by S3.

Conclusion : I don't think it's possible...

Comment: Yeah, Mercurial is very upfront about preferring that you use push and pull over ssh or http to get changesets from here to there.  Samba, nfs, dropbox, and other network file systems all have inconsistances around case sensitively, symlink detection, hard link counts, and other stuff.  Better just to push and push to a hgweb or ssh:// on an ec2 node.  Micros are (almost) free.

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not. I do not know what you consider cheap. I am using it and I get billed $1.6 occasionally. I placed a large backup there. Try it if you like, at the risk of losing $2 or so.

By the way, I suggest using the [S3Organizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3fox/), which is a Firefox extension.